Hibernate @ManyToOne case insensitive
We have two Oracle tables like this:
TABLE_1
-------
CODE_TABLE_1  | LIBEL_TABLE_1
-----------------------------
code_table_1.1| libel_table_1.1
code_table_1.2| libel_table_1.2
code_table_1.3| libel_table_1.3

TABLE_2
-------
CODE_TABLE_2  | LIBEL_TABLE_2    |  CODE_TABLE_1
----------------------------------------------
code_table_2.1| libel_table_2.1  | CODE_TABLE_1.1
code_table_2.2| libel_table_2.2  | CODE_TABLE_1.2
code_table_2.3| libel_table_2.3  | CODE_TABLE_1.3

there is no foreign key between the two table, but You can see that the column CODE_TABLE_1 in TABLE_2 refers to the same column in TABLE_1 but it always on uppercase.
Now I want to create to hibernate entities and make a relation between the two entities while ignoring this case difference like this:
@Table(name = "TABLE_1")
@Entity
@Data
public class Table1{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_TABLE_1")
    private String codeTable1;

    @Column(name = "LIBEL_TABLE_1")
    private String libeleTable1;
}

@Table(name = "TABLE_2")
@Entity
@Data
public class Table2{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE_TABLE_2")
    private String codeTable2;

    @Column(name = "LIBEL_TABLE_2")
    private String libeleTable2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_TABLE_1", referencedColumnName = "CODE_TABLE_1")
    private Table1 table1;
}

The problem as you expect is this relationship doesn't work since there is a case difference between data.
My question is, if there is any way to make thise relationship case insensitive.
PS: We can't change the data direclty in oracle table source to make theme with the same case

Can you add new column to table? ;)

No unfortunately we have no control over the database.

Then you stuck with native querys. It will be extra painful if you have references to that broken entity from other entities, No Hibernate magic for you anymore: no lazy loading,c no cascade updates etc. I sugest you to find a way to fix your DB (you may create view in it) or create new DB and link them. Otherwise you wont enjoy Hibernate.
